# UpdateModel for Nested Properties in ASP.NET MVC2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm currently working my way through the MvcMusicStore tutorial for the second time as a personal project. This time instead of the Entity Framework I'm attempting to use nHibernate and also some IoC using Castle Windsor.

The first hurdle that Ive hit relates to nested classes and model binding. Im able to display a list of albums and then edit them. Im also able to persist changes to database as long as I edit the Title, Price or AlbumArtUrl fields. When I attempt to edit the Artist or Genre fields then the following error occurs.

"The model of type 'MvcMusicStore.Models.Album' could not be updated."

This error occurs on the call to UpdateModel so I'm assuming its something to do with the binding but I'm completely stumped how to proceed. From the searches I've done on StackOverflow and elsewhere this seems to be a common problem but I haven't found a solution so far.

I'm hoping someone can spot what I'm doing wrong here and suggest a solution.

Album

```
public class Album
{
    public virtual int AlbumId { get; set; }
    public virtual Artist Artist { get; set; }
    public virtual Genre Genre { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal Price { get; set; }
    public virtual string AlbumArtUrl { get; set; }
}
```

StoreManagerViewModel

```
public class StoreManagerViewModel
{
    public Album Album { get; set; }
    public IList<Artist> Artists { get; set; }
    public IList<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
}
```

Edit.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="/Views/Shared/Site.Master" 
   Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MvcMusicStore.ViewModels.StoreManagerViewModel>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Edit - <%: Model.Album.Title %>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <h2>Edit Album</h2>

    <% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
        <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Edit Album</legend>
        <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Album, 
            new { Artists = Model.Artists, Genres = Model.Genres}) %>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>

    <% } %>

    <div>
        <%: Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") %>
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

Album.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MvcMusicStore.Models.Album>" %>

<div class="editor-label">
    <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title) %>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Title) %>
    <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title) %>
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price) %>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Price, String.Format("{0:F}", Model.Price)) %>
    <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price) %>
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.AlbumArtUrl) %>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AlbumArtUrl) %>
    <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AlbumArtUrl) %>
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Artist)%>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Artist, new SelectList(ViewData["Artists"] as IEnumerable, "ArtistId", "Name", Model.Artist))%>
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Genre)%>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Genre, new SelectList(ViewData["Genres"] as IEnumerable, "GenreId", "Name", Model.Genre))%>
</div>
```

StoreManagerController

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        var viewModel = new StoreManagerViewModel
        {
            Album = AlbumRepository.GetById(id),
            Genres = GenreRepository.GetAll().ToList(),
            Artists = ArtistRepository.GetAll().ToList(),
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost, UnitOfWork]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection formValues)
    {
        var album = AlbumRepository.GetById(id);

        try
        {
            UpdateModel(album, "Album");
            AlbumRepository.SaveOrUpdate(album);

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            var viewModel = new StoreManagerViewModel
            {
                Album = album,
                Genres = GenreRepository.GetAll().ToList(),
                Artists = ArtistRepository.GetAll().ToList(),
            };

            return View(viewModel);
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE 1:**

If I breakpoint at UpdateModel and look at ValueProvider.GetValue("Album.Artist"), I can see the updated ArtistId. This suggests to me Ive completely misunderstood how this should work.

Should I really be letting UpdateModel handle the properties it can like so:

```
UpdateModel(album, "Album", new string[] { "Title", "Price", "AlbumArtUrl" });
```

And then manually updating the Artist and Genre properties by fetching the objects myself based on the ArtistId, GenreId in the ValueProvider?

**UPDATE 2**

A fix of sorts?

Album.ascx

```
<div class="editor-label">
    <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Artist)%>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Artist, new SelectList(ViewData["Artists"] as IEnumerable, "ArtistId", "Name", Model.Artist.ArtistId))%>
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Genre)%>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Genre, new SelectList(ViewData["Genres"] as IEnumerable, "GenreId", "Name", Model.Genre.GenreId))%>
</div>
```

StoreManagerController

```
UpdateModel(album, "Album", new string[] { "Title", "Price", "AlbumArtUrl" });
album.Artist = ArtistRepository.GetById(Int32.Parse(formValues["Album.Artist"]));
album.Genre = GenreRepository.GetById(Int32.Parse(formValues["Album.Genre"]));
AlbumRepository.SaveOrUpdate(album);
```

This works, I dont know if its how this sort of thing should be done or not. Would appreciate someone putting me right if its not?

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide your logic in `UpdateModel()`

Also if you have strongly typed view, you can use your model as a controller parameter instead FormCollection. Also it is a good practice to exclude id of edited album.

```
ActionResult Edit([Bind(Exclude = "AlbumId")]Album album)
```

And you'll get in album all fields from your form for editing.

About your code:
Now I see in your code that you get by id current album in your db

```
 var album = AlbumRepository.GetById(id);
```

and then try to do some actions with it, and it is not clear how you bind information from view.

Comment: Interesting, if I use my model as the controller parameter instead of FormCollection both the Artist and Genre properties are Null.

Comment: Exactly. If you want to gen not NULL in Artists and Genere you have make you controller available to get such Type of Model. Genre AND Artists are  parts of StoreManagerViewModel, not Album. So you have to understand what really you need in you Edit action. Do You want to update only album entry in your db or do you want update also some related information.
 I think it is useful for you to read about MVC basics and model and data binding.Try to find book here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240905/best-asp-net-mvc-book

Comment: Im a bit confused about what you are saying to be honest, Artist and Genre are both part of Album and it is only the Album record I want to update.

Comment: Sorry. I missed. I think you are speaking about  IList<Artist> in StoreManagerViewModel

Comment: The problem why you get null in Artist and Genre is in how you bind  on your view. Html.DropDownList("Artist"... is incorrect Try to use as you do it in all other fields. Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.Artist... and I think it is a solution

Comment: I tried using DropDownListFor previously and it didnt make any difference, I dont know if I have the SelectList configured correctly or not.

Answer (score 0):

To hack this problem, I created a property in the ViewModel which links to the related object and then did my binding to that property:

---

### **Model**

```
public class User
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Your first name is required.")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Your last name is required.")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }        


    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A logon name is required.")]
    public string Logon { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A password is required.")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A role is required.")]
    public string Role { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "An airport is required.")]
    public Airport Airport { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Is Active")]
    bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

### **View**

```
       <div class="form-field">
            <div class="field-label"><%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.User.Airport) %>:</div>
            <div class="field-input"><%= Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.UserAirportId, new SelectList(Model.Airports, "Id", "Name"))%></div>
            <div class="field-result"><%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.User.Airport) %></div>
        </div>
```

### **ViewModel**

```
    public class UserViewModel
{
    public User User { get; set; }
    public List<Airport> Airports { get; set; }
    public List<String> Roles { get; set; }

    //Hack to get around non-binding of complex objects by UpdateModel
    public Guid UserAirportId
    {
        get
        {
            if (User != null && User.Airport != null)
                return User.Airport.Id;

            return Guid.Empty;
        }

        set
        {
            if (User == null)
                return;

            var airport = Airports.Where(m => m.Id == value).FirstOrDefault();

            if (airport == null)
                return;

            User.Airport = airport;
        }
    }
}
```